# Slow loading of images in UITableViewCell since Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, image-processing, xcode11

We have an application that has been running for years using UITableViewCells containing thumbnail images stored locally. The loading of images was never a problem and scrolling was fast. Since the latest Xcode update it has become sticky and images are loading slowly. I've implemented asynchronous loading to try and solve this and scrolling is smooth but there is a significant lag in loading images which is unacceptable.

Has anyone else experienced this? What has changed in Xcode 11 to cause this?

For what it's worth, here is the code I have now:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    let ImageLoaded = g_resources.readTreeImage(id: UInt(initData.IconImageID) ?? 0)

    if(initData.IconImageID != nil)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            self.m_treeImageView.image = ImageLoaded

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue on a real device? try it on real device and check. Xcode 11 is lagging out, crashing, simulator doesn't animate correctly and lags, stalls, crashes, all the time for many folks including myself. lots of weird bugs but when app is used on real device, that behavior goes away.

Comment: Same on real device. We tried a few devices and all have the same behaviour. Older devices are worse